# drupal-6 admin pages disappeared after importing content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

After importing a cck definition the page timed out, since then there are several pages that I can't access and don't show up in the navigation, for example:

- admin/build/modules
- admin/user/user
- admin/user/permisions
- admin/settings/site-information
- admin/content/types/import

Anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update your site as following

www.yoursitename.com/update.php

May be it will help you.